# Search text and use specific formula for text found

Tags: excel, excel-formula, find, office365

I have a table like this

[image: Text to find]

On the left : list of text I'm looking for in a cell. On the right : formula I'll use depending on the text I've found. The formula is necessary for a text extraction (which is not the same regarding the text I've found).

The question is : How can I search for this list of text in one cell and then returning the associated formula to use ?

EDIT : What I'm looking for :
[image]

As you can see, I have random texts in each lines, and I want to extract specific content. I cannot use If..if..if.. because of the Excel limitation.

Inputs :

lrh34gero egepjpj I28595474 erqm567goh

gerlkq $ONE-234556 ethrh3444rzh

zrlthk 4555 njwhv ùpbozj LFO-FIN-25436545

Comment: Post your input and then show your desired output. To run formula from cells, you need `VBA` coding.

Comment: @Harun24hr I've edited my post. I won't use VBA. I'll use a workaround for my formulas. This is another debate. Here I'm trying to understand how I can search for texts in a cell and get reference of the text I've found in my table (1st table)

Comment: Do you have any chance to match multiple value from list of `A2:A6` cells in single cell of your input (in screenshot)?

Comment: What version of Excel have you got? Also, can you post the data as markdown sample data instead?

Comment: Also please post those data text so that we can copy.

Comment: No never, it's only 1 match or 0

Comment: Input data is in plain text now. @JvdV I'm using the last version from O365 product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nested `BYROW()` function with `FILTERXML()`. Try-

```
=BYROW(B3:B4,LAMBDA(z,TEXTJOIN("",1,BYROW(A2:A4,LAMBDA(x,IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(z," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., '" &x&"')]"),""))))))
```

To know details about `FILTERXML()` please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/5514747) from JvdV.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is one option:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=MAP(A2:A4,LAMBDA(s,LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(s," "),@SORT(XLOOKUP(D2:D6&"*",x,x,"",2),,-1))))
```

**Note**: This assumes that your listvalues are always at the start of a word (string get's split on space). If not the case, then still split it but use an extra asterisk in your lookup:

```
=MAP(A2:A4,LAMBDA(s,LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(s," "),@SORT(XLOOKUP("*"&D2:D6&"*",x,x,"",2),,-1))))
```

Comment: Shorter one. I forgot about `xlookup()` wild card matching option.

Comment: Thank you. It's almost working but in some cases, the word I have to find can be join on other word (like zetrthRC-LFO-FIN-123456-zertsn)

Comment: Then simply add an asterisk in front of the 1st parameter in xlookup